# NASM, read a file and print the content

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I have this piece of code in NASM (for linux) that supposed to open an existing file, read it and print the content on the screen, but does not work, can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?(`hello.txt` is the name of the file)

```
section .data

file db "./hello.txt", 0

len equ 1024

section .bss 

buffer: resb 1024


section .text

global _start

_start:

    mov ebx, [file] ; name of the file  
    mov eax, 5  
    mov ecx, 0  
    int 80h     

    mov eax, 3  
    mov ebx, eax
    mov ecx, buffer 
    mov edx, len    
    int 80h     

    mov eax, 4  
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, buffer 
    mov edx, len    
    int 80h     

    mov eax, 6  
    int 80h     

    mov eax, 1  
    mov ebx, 0 
    int 80h
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mov ebx, [file] ; name of the file  
mov eax, 5  
mov ecx, 0  
int 80h
```

Is wrong.  Loose the square brackets around `file`.  You are passing the file name instead of a pointer to the filename.

```
mov ebx, file ; const char *filename
mov eax, 5  
mov ecx, 0  
int 80h
```

Answer (score 3):

I see here a lot of mistakes, in order:

```
mov ebx, [file] ; name of the file  
mov eax, 5  
mov ecx, 0  
int 80h
```

Here, as said, u must lose square brackets (because the function needs a pointer, not a value)

```
mov eax, 3  
mov ebx, eax
mov ecx, buffer 
mov edx, len    
int 80h
```

Here, u must save the file descriptor from eax, before writing there value 3, else u just loose it

```
mov eax, 4  
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, buffer 
mov edx, len    
int 80h
```

Well. Here u using ebx register, so better way is to save file descriptor in memory. And for display, you take 1024 bytes from buffer, which is not correct. After reading from the file, the eax register will contain the number of characters read, so after reading from the file it will be better to store the value from the eax register in edx

```
mov eax, 6  
int 80h
```

Again. U close the file, but ebx contains dirt, although it must contain a file descriptor

Correct code must look like this:

```
section .data
  file db "text.txt",0 ;filename ends with '\0' byte
section .bss
  descriptor resb 4 ;memory for storing descriptor
  buffer resb 1024
  len equ 1024
section .start
global _start
_start:
  mov eax,5 ;open
  mov ebx,file ;filename
  mov ecx,0 ;read only
  int 80h ;open filename for read only

  mov [descriptor],eax ;storing the descriptor

  mov eax,3 ;read from file
  mov ebx,[descriptor] ;your file descriptor
  mov ecx,buffer ;read to buffer
  mov edx,len ;read len bytes
  int 80h ;read len bytes to buffer from file

  mov edx,eax ;storing count of readed bytes to edx
  mov eax,4 ;write to file
  mov ebx,1 ;terminal
  mov ecx,buffer ;from buffer
  int 80h ;write to terminal all readed bytes from buffer

  mov eax,6 ;close file
  mov ebx,[descriptor] ;your file descriptor
  int 80h ;close your file

  mov eax,1
  mov ebx,0
  int 80h
```

This is not a perfect code, but it should work

Comment: Wow, that's hilarious that the code happened to work because `__NR_read` = 3 = first free fd number after stdin, stdout, and stderr.  So a successful `open()` would return 3, unless you ran the program with `./a.out 3</dev/null` or something, or closed `stderr`.

Comment: You could have `push`ed the descriptor, or better copied it to `esi` or something.  No need to have static storage for an integer temporary.  Or better, `mov ebx, eax` / `mov eax, 3`.  You don't have to assign registers in any order, as long as they have the right value when you `int 0x80`.  Also, you could do the `close()` before `write()` so you'd still have the fd in `ebx`.

Comment: Good point that you should `write()` with a len matching what you got from `read()`, but you forgot to fix that in your version :P  You still have the OP's silly `mov edx, len`.

Comment: *U close the file, but ebx contains dirt,*  Actually, `ebx=1` there, so it closes stdout.  Linux's `int 0x80` ABI preserves all registers (except eax of course), so ebx still has the value from `mov ebx,1`.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls).